# Why is my button script not working?

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript

Okay so i'm new to C# and i made this script. The goal i have in mind is that when the player is on the button and presses a button ( W in this case ) the button is switched from on to off ( or vice versa). The problem i have is that when the character stands on the button and presses W it doesn't always switch its state and i have no idea why. Any info would be appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Button : MonoBehaviour {
     public bool Pressed = false;
     Animator Anim;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         Anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
         Anim.SetBool ("Pressed", Pressed);
     }
     void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other){
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
            if (Pressed){
                Pressed = false;
            } else {
                Pressed = true;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As informed by the auto-generated comment, these methods are called at every frame, which means between 60 and 120 times every second approximately.

When you press `W`, you can be sure it lasts more than 1/100 seconds, which means the `bool` will switch values many times, and you have 50% chances that in the end you have what you wanted, and 50% chances that you don't.

Comment: how would i go about fixing that?

Comment: One way would be to know if the key has been released before pressing again. I am not a unity expert but there are methods detecting that for sure, I will let you search that by yourself :)